# npm start NOT in localhost

Tags: npm, npm-start

i am trying to run a server using the command `npm start`.
however, this automatically runs on http://localhost:1234
i would like to run this selecting the host, so anyone connected to my net 192.xxx.x.xxx is able to access the server online.

i tried to change the package.json including this but it doesnt work:

`"scripts": { "start": "webpack-dev-server --host 192.xxx.x.xxx" }`

it seems that you have to change something about this package,